# curl - There is conflicting information between the SSL connection, its certificate and/or the included HTTP requests

Tags: php, curl, endpoint

I am using DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS using cURL with a HTTPv1 API

The sandbox http://165.227.5.96/customer_create_test.php

The error "There is conflicting information between the SSL connection, its certificate and/or the included HTTP requests."

I'm using digital ocean servers and they are running on Heroku servers and this is the response I'm getting. What is wrong here with this code I am not seeing. Here is the API doc https://api.shop-ware.com/api/v1/docs.

** I have deleted the Digicert or any SSL certificates on my end.
** I removed our API keys.

```
// Set post field varaibles from form post from the checkin forms 'New Customer'
$post = [
'first_name' => 'John',
'last_name' => 'Doe',
'email' => 'john@doe.com',
'phones[number]' => '+18880003333',
'phones[label]' => 'cell',
'phones[perferred]' => 'true',
'detail' => 'test customer 1',
'address' => '300 H Street',
'city' => 'Vegas',
'state' => 'NV',
'zip' => '81911',
'marketing_ok' => '1'
];

//Initate cURL to POST to the New Customer to the endpoint -> /api/v1/tenants/1/customers
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.shop-ware.com/api/v1/tenants/1/customers"); //live endpoint
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.shop-ware-api-sandbox.com/api/v1/tenants/1/customers"); //sandbox endpoint
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Post true 1 false 0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);  //Post array
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //Accept response

//Headers required by Shopware
$headers = [
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json',
'X-Api-Partner-Id: id-here',
'X-Api-Secret: key-here',
'Host: http://165.227.5.96/customer_create_test.php'

];

//Set HTTP headers required by Shopware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//Get response from Shopware
$shopware_output = curl_exec ($ch);

//Close cURL connection with Shopware
curl_close ($ch);

//Display response
var_dump($shopware_output);
```

I'm getting a strange response that I do not understand when running curl from the API endpoint server and I'm just not sure what to make of it.

Digging deeper here, I ran curl to the end point through terminal, here are some key pieces of the response.

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Cowboy
```

I went to the API providers host Heroku. I dug further and found this https://help.heroku.com/8SZE5IG4/why-am-i-seeing-a-certificate-mismatch-error-when-i-access-my-custom-domain-over-ssl-tls

Does this have to do with my server or the API providers Heroku server?

Comment: Please refrain from posting unnecessary extra levels of indentation in your code blocks.

Comment: I will not do that anymore. Could you help answer my question?

Comment: Are you using Nginx or something similar for your server? I found some other similar threads on this problem and it seems to pertain to hosting, not your code.

Comment: I am using digital ocean running ubuntu servers

Comment: Yes, what is your hosting solution, are you using Apache or nginx? Run `sudo service nginx status` and `sudo service apache2 status` to see if either shows a running service to check if you don't know

Comment: I am using DigitalOcean Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS apache. I did a lot of updates to the original thread. Please see. The API provider says it is not an issue on their end but I found this https://help.heroku.com/8SZE5IG4/why-am-i-seeing-a-certificate-mismatch-error-when-i-access-my-custom-domain-over-ssl-tls they use Heroku, the API provider. I just emailed them with the write up. We'll see what they say.